# Collectors.groupingBy - collecting to list of some property of Object instead of list of Object itself

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

Lets say I have a class

```java
public class FootBallTeam {
    private String name; // team name
    private String league;

    //getters, setters, etc.
}
```

I'm trying to group *Teams names* according to their *League*.
For example:

```
League A -> [nameOfTeam2, nameOfTeam5]
League B -> [nameOfTeam1, nameOfTeam3, nameOfTeam4]
```

With below code I am getting `Map<String, List<FootBallTeam>>` which is pointing to list of team objects `List<FootBallTeam>`.

```java
Map<String, List<FootBallTeam>> teamsGroupedByLeague = list
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FootBallTeam::getLeague));
```

Instead I just want the names of FootBallTeams i.e. FootBallTeam.name.
In other words `Map<String, List<String>>` where `List<String>` holds *teams names* .

How to achieve that?

Comment: Note: if you want to find which teams belong to a *particular* league, then you could simply use `list.stream().filter(team -> Objects.equals(team.getLeague(), yourParticularLeague)).map(FootBallTeam::getName).toList()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want the names of FootTeams i.e. `FootBallTeam.name`

You need to apply additional *collector* [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) as a *downstream collector* of `groupingBy()`

```
Map<String, List<String>> teamNamesByLeague = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        FootBallTeam::getLeague,
        Collectors.mapping(FootBallTeam::getName,
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Comment: can you please explain how this will work `Collectors.mapping(FootBallTeam::getName,Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @SaveSoil The first argument of `mapping` is a *function* that transforms  the stream element (method reference `FootBallTeam::getName` implies that we need to extract a name from the `FootBallTeam` object). The second argument is a *downstream collector*, which describes how these transformed  objects should be accumulated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collectors.mapping:`

```
Map<String, List<String>> total = footBallTeamList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        FootBallTeam::getLeague,
                        Collectors.mapping(FootBallTeam::getName, Collectors.toList())));;
```